# Can I make a static factory method in an abstract class?

Tags: java

I am making a chess game and trying to figure out if there is a way to make my abstract class "Piece" have a method that returns a new instance of the concrete implementations like Pawn or Rook.

For example:

```
static public Piece newNorthPiece(){
        return new Piece(true);
    }
```

Except instead of returning a Piece I want it to return whatever the class that called the method is. So if I call Pawn.newNorthPiece() I want it to return to me a new Pawn(true).
And I would like to do this without having to write a new factory method for every class that extends the Piece class.

Comment: You need to call a concrete implementation. So either `KnightPiece`, `PawnPiece` etc. Your factory methods should determine which implementation to call. Do you have `Pawn` defined yet?

Comment: I am fairly certain this is not possible. The superclass isn't aware of its subclasses. The real question is why you don't want to write a new factory method for every class.

Comment: Obicere I'm not sure what you mean by that, but I have made classes for all the pieces already yes.

Comment: @OdinThorsen He is telling you to write a separate factory method for each class.

Comment: Gendarme because I try not to repeat myself, and I hoped there would be a way to just make this once in the abstract class, it would be much neater that way

Comment: In rough outline, something like:
`public abstract class Piece { public static <T extends Piece> Piece factory(Class<T> pieceType) { return pieceType.newInstance();} ... }`
but as you can see this isn't really buying you anything. Using `new` to create pieces isn't really "repeating yourself", and "I try not to repeat myself" is not necessarily a good engineering principle when repetition is actually inevitable.

Comment: You already know you need, say, a `Pawn` or `Rook`. A factory method is for when you only know that you need the supertype. Demanding a particular subtype defeats that anonymity, and leaves you actually writing more than simply `Pawn blackQPawn = new Pawn();`. A factory class as it should be is `Arrays.asList(E ... item)`. You only know that you get back a `List<E>`; you cannot know which subtype. Don't apply "I try not to repeat myself" as a mantra. Think through the engineering problem and determine good logical sense. Factories for specific types aren't.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback I appreciate it. I don't mind doing something twice if I have to but if there was an easy way to solve this once I would have liked to know, that's all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java, you can't do that as `super class` does not know how many `classes` are extending it. The closest you can get to it is by implementing the method like this:

```
class Piece {
    public static Piece getInstance(Class<? extends Piece> clazz) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException{
        return clazz.newInstance();
    }
}

class Pawn extends Piece {

}
```

You can then call the method and pass `Piece`'s class like this:

```
Piece piece = Piece.getInstance(Pawn.class);
```

This will give you the instance of `Pawn` class, you can use it to get the instance of any other class that extends `Piece`.

P.S. This depends on a couple of factors (e.g. child class having a `public constructor`, `Piece` class having access to child class etc)

Comment: This seems like the closest to what I wanted so far, great idea!

Comment: @OdinThorsen this will also help validating all the `Piece` implementations to have at least one `public` constructor as instance won't be created otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I make a static factory method in an abstract class?

Yes, you can create a `static` method inside `abstract` class and the method will look the below:

```
public abstract class PieceFactory {

    public static Piece getPiece(String pieceType){
        switch(pieceType) {
            case NorthPiece:  
                  return new NorthPiece();  

            case Pawn: 
                  return new Pawn();  
          }
     }
 }
```

And you can call the `PieceFactory.getPiece("Pawn")` whichn returns the instance of `Pawn`.

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for because I would like the Piece class to not know what classes would be extending it. I appreciate the suggestion anyway :)

Comment: It is a `PieceFactory`, not a `Piece`, please have a look at the above code now

Comment: Oh that's an interesting solution, I'll try that!

Answer (score -1):

The `Piece` class is `abstract`, so you cannot instantiate it. You need to have a concrete implementation of your `Piece` class.